# Html regex leading and trailing words

Tags: html, regex, tags, bold

I have a feeling that I'm really missing something obvious here but I'm looking for a regex that will match the content of a bold tag plus the words immediatly before and after the tags.

So:

```
"start this string <b>is the text</b> we need end"
```

would match to

```
"string <b>is the text</b> we"
```

I can get to the tags and their content with `<b\s*>(.*?|[^>\s]+)<\/b\s*>` but I can't seem to nail down the leading and trailing words.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want a regex to get for example, `string <b>is the text</b> we` from `start this string <b>is the text</b> we need end`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused why `.*?|[^>\s]+` is in the middle there.  What does it buy over plain `.*?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (based on your regex):

```
/\w+\s*<b\s*>(?:.*?|[^>\s]+)<\/b\s*>\s*\w+/
```

See it on [Rubular regex tester](http://www.rubular.com/r/ZqQNHfr0gN)

But perhaps this would be better:

```
/\w+\s*<b\s*>.*?<\/b\s*>\s*\w+/
```

See it on [Rubular regex tester](http://www.rubular.com/r/m0aSztYZhl)

Comment: I'm a bit confused why `.*?|[^>\s]+` is in the middle there.  What does it buy over plain `.*?`?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Nothing, as far as I can see. But I based this off the OP's regex which has this.